# Breaking a uneven value using an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an array to break down values equally into  8 parts evenly.

```
    Dim nTotes As Long
Dim qtyPerDelivery() As Long
Dim qtyAddition As Long
Dim deliveriesPerDay As Long
Dim newOrder As cOrder
Dim RedistCount As Long
Dim AACPD As String
Dim msg As String
'Make sure to add Sheet1 as Worksheet object
'Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
'Dim pname As cPart

AACPD = AACPartDesignator

deliveriesPerDay = 8
     RedistCount = 0
      m = 0
      g = 0
      k = 7
      r = 0
      o = 8

'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
'
''Set pname = New cPart
'pname.partNumber = Part.partNumber

  If (Part.partNumber = "357098GB100") Then

  ToteQty = 108

  End If

  If ((AACTruckCount > 0) And (AACTruckCount < 10)) Then
    deliveriesPerDay = AACTruckCount
  End If
 ReDim qtyPerDelivery(1 To deliveriesPerDay) As Long


  nTotes = RequiredQuantity / ToteQty



  If ((RequiredQuantity / ToteQty) - (RequiredQuantity \ ToteQty)) <> 0 Then
    nTotes = nTotes + 1
  End If

  i = nLastShipmentAddedTo

      ' Do While (nTotes > 0)
       '  If i > deliveriesPerDay Then i = 1      ' reset to first truck after getting to truck 8
        ' nLastShipmentAddedTo = i                ' todo how many deliveries per part?
        ' qtyPerDelivery(i) = qtyPerDelivery(i) + 1 'increases the(1 X 8) array 1 numeration eight times if i > 8 the cycle is reset and the cycle repeats for the next numeration Ex.
         'msg = qtyPerDelivery(i)
        ' AddToTruckLogFile msg
         'nTotes = nTotes - 1 'Subtracts from number of totes
        ' msg = nTotes
        ' AddToTruckLogFile msg
        ' i = i + 1 'adds  1 to addtional of the cycle
         'msg = i & " " & nLastShipmentAddedTo
        ' AddToTruckLogFile msg
        ' AddToTruckLogFile msg
       'Loop


 r = nTotes
Do While (nTotes > 0)
    i = o - k
If r Mod o = 0 Then
        qtyPerDelivery(i) = r / o
ElseIf nTotes Mod o = 0 Then
       q = nTotes / o
Else
     If (nTotes / o) = 1 Then
         q = 1
     Else
         q = (nTotes / o) + 1
         qtyPerDelivery(i) = q
     End If

End If
  k = k - 1
  nTotes = nTotes - qtyPerDelivery(i)
Loop
```

I know there is a better way for my approach of handling the remainder of values that cannot break into eight evenly. 
for example if the ntotes are 14 my current script will break it into
 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1

I'm looking to make the values as even as possible for the uneven values 
3 2 2 2 2 1 1 1

I know the portion of code is  a lil messy I've been sick but I'm looking into what ideas may work. 
Update:

I tried to not include as much arbitrary details as I possibly again since this is a portion of a much larger code the portion of the code passes the a quantity value which is used to calculate the number of totes `ntotes` which this number is broken down into an array into 8 equal parts ( if possible) for example what if the ntote value is 80 then the array qtyperdeliveries will contain

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
since 80 can be broken into eight parts evenly but for a number like 84  we will have a remainder of  4  that I would like to see broken up in this fashion.

11 11 11 11 10 10 10 10

The problem I am having is that I am having is emulating this via code my current code doesn't execute this smoothly it does not distribute the remainder as evenly as my example to keep the values as even as they can possibly can be when dealing with a nTote value. What I've written to tackle this portion was my best attempt but still incorrect.

```
Do While (nTotes > 0)
    i = o - k
If r Mod o = 0 Then
        qtyPerDelivery(i) = r / o
ElseIf nTotes Mod o = 0 Then
       q = nTotes / o
      qtyPerDelivery(i) = q

Else
     If (nTotes / o) = 1 Then
         q = 1
       qtyPerDelivery(i) = q
     Else
         q = (nTotes / o) + 1
         qtyPerDelivery(i) = q
     End If

End If
  k = k - 1
  nTotes = nTotes - qtyPerDelivery(i)
Loop
```

Comment: First of all, what is `cOrder` and what is `AACPartDesignator`. It would be great if you could provide us sample data and working code to be able to reproduce. Try to only include those part of the code that revolve around your issue. Or better simplify some code to demonstrate your goal.

Comment: *"I'm looking to make the values as even as possible for the uneven values"* - can you explain what you mean by this? How is `3 2 2 2 2 1 1 1` more appropriate than `3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1`? Because it contains more even value integers?

Comment: That was a bad example due to my rushing what I meant was I want to break any number into an array containing nearly equal values such that if there is an remainder it gets broken up and distributed evenly like 84 would be 11 11 11 11 10 10 10 10. I just have a problem in how to do this effectively from a coding aspect.

Comment: If `n = 8q+r` (where `q = Int(n/8)`)  then `n` can be partitioned into `r` numbers of size `q+1` and `8-r` numbers of size `q`. The logic is to give each partition cell the integer quotient (`q`) items, then take case of any remainder `r` by splitting it between `r` cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic function that will do what you want:

```
Function DivideEvenly(ByVal arg_lQty As Long, ByVal arg_lDivisor As Long) As Variant

    If arg_lDivisor = 0 Then
        DivideEvenly = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim lQuotient As Long
    lQuotient = Int(arg_lQty / arg_lDivisor)

    Dim lRemainder As Long
    lRemainder = Abs(arg_lQty Mod arg_lDivisor)

    Dim aResults() As Variant
    ReDim aResults(1 To Abs(arg_lDivisor))

    Dim ixResult As Long
    For ixResult = LBound(aResults) To UBound(aResults)
        Select Case (lQuotient > 0)
            Case True:  aResults(ixResult) = lQuotient + Abs(ixResult <= lRemainder)
            Case Else:  aResults(ixResult) = lQuotient + Abs(ixResult > lRemainder)
        End Select
    Next ixResult

    DivideEvenly = aResults

End Function
```

And here's how you would call it:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim qtyPerDelivery() As Variant

    qtyPerDelivery = DivideEvenly(84, 8)
    MsgBox Join(qtyPerDelivery, ", ")   'Checking results -> 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub myarray()
Dim div As Long
div = 8 ' the number of items in array

Dim vl As Long
vl = 84 'the starting value

Dim ev As Long
ev = Int(vl / div) 'get the base number

Dim arr(1 To div) As Long 'create the array

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To div 'loop the number of times
    If i <= vl Mod div Then 'check the left overs
        arr(i) = ev + 1 'add 1 to the array if less than the left overs
    Else
        arr(i) = ev 'other wise put the base
    End If
    Debug.Print arr(i) 'just to show the output of the array.
Next i

End Sub
```